# How to enable Comments notification?

Tags: bug, comments

I don't receive any other person's comments notification after my comments on another person's answer/question . I have to open the post itself to view. Is there a setting with which I can enable?

I mainly use Islam se using chrome on my mobile .
I haven't checked if I am getting the notification on my laptop's chrome.

Comment: You on;y get notified of comments when you are mentioned by name with an @ sign preceding your name, or when the comment is on your own post (as is the case of this comment). Other than that, you have to open the post to check on other comments as you mentioned you do. On another note, you can install the StackExchange app for a better user experience on your mobile phone.

Comment: Ok @III-AK-III thanks .. just testing by tagging you now

Comment: I am not able to tag you as well...is mobile site of se an issue ?

Comment: Tagging might take some time on a mobile app and you may need lots of attempts to retry it, that's my experience. As for comments you get comments of other on your own posts or when a person is addressing you in particular using the "@" symbol/sign succeeded by your user name. On the mobile app there's a special symbol to address comments of other users directly, as addressing them yourself is rather difficult. For example your user name includes a space therefore it would be difficult for others to address you from a mobile without this symbol.